# Netlogo plot don't show the result

Tags: plot, netlogo

I want to show in a plot the result of two different global values, but nothing is showing on the plot after the go (forever) button is pressed.
Here my initial configuration ( after go, red possession and blue possesion were increased by always 1 every ticks) :
[image: inital configuration]

So I try to plot somethings like ticks or count turtles but ,after press go button the result is the same.
Here is how I configured my plot.
What am I doing wrong?
[image: Plot configuration]

I am using netlogo 6.0.4

Comment: is it's the same code as your other question, you have never used `tick` to increment the tick counter, so `ticks` is always equal to 0

Comment: ticks are not auto incremented by the buttons go?

Comment: no. typically you place the `tick` command as the last command in the go procedure. The go button is simply an instruction to run the procedure named go (or whatever other command you put in the dialogue box). The forever checkbox says to keep on calling it.

Comment: I didn't know I hade to use tick in go procedure, I thought It was automatic. Now It works, thank you